# Writing all data at once to parquet file using structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I wish to write all aggregated data from a Kafka topic to a parquet file at once (or at least end up with one parquet file in the end).

I run a separate producer app that puts 50 messages on the topic.
The data is aggregated by time (1 day) in a consumer app, so I need to gather all data from 1 day and count it. This works and is done like this:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVER)
                .option("subscribe", "test")
                .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
                .option("group.id", "test")
                .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
                .option("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer")
                .option("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
                .load()

// LEFT OUT CODE FOR READABILITY

                .withWatermark("timestamp", "1 minutes")
                .groupBy(
                        functions.window(new Column("timestamp"), "1 day", "1 day"),
                        new Column("container_nummer"))
                .count();
```

The results are then written to a parquet file like this:

```
StreamingQuery query = df.writeStream()
                .format("parquet")
                .option("truncate", "false")
                .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/kafka-logs")
                .start("/Users/**/kafka-path");

query.awaitTermination();
```

If I write this to console, I end up with the correct counts for each day in batch 1. When trying to write it to parquet, I only end up with multiple, empty parquet files. I read them like this:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("test")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
                .parquet("/Users/**/kafka-path/part-00000-dd416263-8db1-4166-b243-caba470adac7-c000.snappy.parquet");

        df.explain();
        df.show(20);
```

all of the parquet files seem to be empty (in contrast to writing them to console), the code above outputting this:

```
+------+----------------+-----+
|window|container_nummer|count|
+------+----------------+-----+
+------+----------------+-----+
```

I have two questions:

- What is/are possible reasons that my parquet files are empty?
- Is it possible to to have 1 complete parquet file with all data in it in the end? I want to use this data to feed a machine learning model in a different program.

Note: it does not need to run in production. I just hope someone knows a way for this to work..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to write aggregated data as Parquet files?

Answer (score 1):

The component involved in reading the ongoing stream is structured streaming. So, you are basically reading an unbounded stream of messages/records that will have to be written as and when the data arrives. With this as the base, Spark will keep assigning the executors to do the read/write operation and there will be multiple files that are created as a part of this process. So, you will not have one single file having all the data. Below is the syntax that can be used to write to parquet file:

```
df..writeStream.queryName("Loantxns_view").outputMode("append").format("parquet").option("path", "/user/root/Ln_sink2").option("checkpointLocation", "/user/root/Checkpoints2").start()
```

Try to read the parquet file using the below mechanism and see if you get the data you are looking for (ParquetDF is a new dataframe that is read by reading the parquet directory path):

```
val ParquetDF = spark.read.parquet("/user/root/Ln_sink2")
    ParquetDF.createOrReplaceTempView("xxxx_view");
    spark.sql("select * from xxxx_view").show(false);
```

Try this and see if the data is visible.